# Parameter tuning using GridSearchCV

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using pipeline in Gridsearch cv object to tune parameters.My code is as follows

```
X_train = df_train.drop("SalePrice", axis=1)
Y_train = df_train["SalePrice"]
X_test  = df_test.drop("Id", axis=1).copy()
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
param_grid={'features__pca__n_components':[1, 2, 3,5,10],}
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler),('algorithm',lr)])
gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, scoring='f1')
gs.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print "Best estimator",gs.best_estimator_
clf = gs.best_estimator_
# fit the optimal model
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
# predict based on the optimal model
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
acc_log = round(clf.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
acc_log
```

I am getting this error where X_train and Y_train parameters are numpy arrays.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-681-9e3b37600170> in <module>()
      7 pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler),('algorithm',lr)])
      8 gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, scoring='f1')
----> 9 gs.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     10 print "Best estimator",gs.best_estimator_
     11 clf = gs.best_estimator_


ValueError: Invalid parameter features for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))), ('algorithm', LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

How should I configure parameters?

Kindly help me solve this.Thanks

Comment: I believe the issue is with the `'features__pca__n_components'`, since you do not have a `features` (nor a `pca`) step. Also, you are not using your PCA anywhere. Try: `pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler), ('pca', PCA()), ('algorithm',lr)])` and for the parameters `param_grid={'pca__n_components':[1, 2, 3,5,10],}`

Comment: @mkaran Thanks for pointing out